# Problems wits xslt processor in WSO2

Tags: xslt, xpath, wso2, saxon

In wso2 esb 4.9.0 I defined next xslt mediator:

```
<localEntry key="TestXslt">
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">            
        <xsl:param name="param1">
            <FileList>
                <File Name="b" automated="false" valid="true"/>
                <File Name="c" automated="false" valid="true"/>
                <File Name="d" automated="false" valid="true"/>
                <File Name="e" automated="false" valid="true"/>
                <File Name="f" automated="false" valid="true"/>
            </FileList>
        </xsl:param>
        <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
                <xsl:for-each select="$param1/FileList/File">
                    <qq>TEST</qq>
                </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
    <description/>
</localEntry>
```

This xslt just shoul create 5 xml tags. Expected output:

```
<qq>TEST</qq>
<qq>TEST</qq>
<qq>TEST</qq>
<qq>TEST</qq>
<qq>TEST</qq>
```

But when i call this xslt mediator, my message is empty.
What i may do wrong. May be i should activate XSLT 2.0. How can i do it?

Comment: Is there perhaps any default namespace declaration (e.g. `xmlns="http://example.com"`) in scope from ancestors of the `localEntry` element? In that case add `<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="">` or at least `<xsl:param name="param1" xmlns="">`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks, that helps, but what should i do, if my param have required xmlns, e.g. <xsl:param name="param1" xmlns="http://atria.cz/medical/integration/patient/"> In this case select="$param1/FileList/File" does not working again

Comment: Then you need to use `<xsl:for-each xpath-default-namespace="http://atria.cz/medical/integration/patient/" select="$param1/FileList/File">`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks so much! This helps me when i declare variables inside xslt stylesheet. But when i get variable from parameter (which pass with call xslt mediator) with `<xsl:param name="param1" xmlns="atria.cz/medical/integration/patient/">` this does not working again,  although i set `xpath-default-namespace="http://atria.cz/medical/integration/patient/" `. Very strange...  Furthermore, when i call `select="count($PARAM_FROM_CALL/descendant::*)"` for param, which passed, returns 0. But for param which declare inside stylesheet this returns 5

Comment: I am afraid I can't solve that last problem you mention as I don't use `wso` or its xslt mediator and I don't know how they pass parameters to Saxon, something seems wrong with the parameter passing, hopefully others with inside into wso read your question and can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside WSO2, the param you pass to your TestXslt with xslt mediator become a string.

Why can't you work with the current payload message, what are you trying to do ?

If you need current message's XML payload + an other xml source (loaded from the registry for exemple) in your xsl, you can add this xml fragment inside the current message before calling xslt mediator. Use enrich mediator exemple :

```
<enrich>
  <source clone="true" xpath="get-property('some_external_xml')"/>
  <target type="body" action="child"/>
</enrich>
```